# CSS3 - Create folded corner background

Tags: css

Trying to figure out, if it's possible to create such background in pure css?

[image]

Comment: Could you post some of the code your have tried? This isn't a request board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with comment that this is not a request board. You should have tried something first.

Here's a starting point for you anyway:

```css
.circle{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:51%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background:#A1C700;
  clip: rect(10px, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  position: absolute;
  display:table;
}

.circle:before {
    content: "";
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 51%;
    background: #83A100;
    position: absolute;
    top: -180px;
    left: 0px;
}

span{
  display:table-cell;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span>Don't worry.<br>Be happy.</span></div>
```

(At least try to do something next time)

### Bonus: [Animated version](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/4uw6sjwL/2/)

(Update: `clip` no longer respects `rotation` so `.container` was needed)

Comment: The best answer ever, thanks! I actually tried bunch of stuff, but didn't come any near the desired result, so I thought posting a code example that is completely wrong doesn't make any sense and makes the question  just less clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this way. :)
But Miro's answer is the best :)
https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/29gmrnh3/

```
#background{
  background:silver;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}
#big_circle{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#99e600;
  margin-top:100px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
}
#small_circle{
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:silver;
 margin-left:95px;
 margin-top:105px;
  position:absolute;
 border-bottom:25px solid #669900;
  -ms-transform: rotate(38deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(38deg);
    z-index:5;
}


<div id="background">

<div id="big_circle"></div>
<div id="small_circle"></div>

</div>
```